# Can WCF duplex service be used to call client when client is offline?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible a service to call client after 4 -5 days when client is offline? e.g. 
1. The client request some reports through service. 
2. Service updates database with client request.
3. Offline work is done on the request 
4. Report is uploaded to the database.

Can we service call its client and send report as soon as report is uploaded to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can WCF duplex service be used to call client when client is offline?

Yes.  WCF can be configured to use MSMQ as a transport.  MSMQ is the **only WCF** transport that allows for all three:

- disconnected scenarios
- resume when computer becomes online and
- optionally provide a level of guaranteed delivery

MSDN:

> If you need to support disconnected queuing, use **netMsmqBinding**. Queuing is provided by using Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) as a transport, which enables support for **disconnected operations**, failure isolation, and load leveling. [more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649887.aspx)

Essentially you invoke a WCF method (send a MSMQ message) and it will be delivered when the computer comes on-line again.  Assuming you have set the appropriate expiration options.